# Socket.io in loopback4

Tags: node.js, socket.io, loopback4

I want to implement socket in loopback 4, I am failed to the established connection between from the frontEnd

```
  var serverStartedTime = (new Date).getTime();
  const io = require('socket.io')(await app.start());
  io.on('connection', (socket: any) => {
    console.log("Socket Connection estiblished")
    app.io.emit('chat message', {startTime: serverStartedTime});
  })
```

Please anyone can help me in this

Comment: Is this code on application.ts? Your question seems to be incomplete. Brief your question.

Comment: This is the code which I have written in index.ts file parallel to application.ts @Madaky

Comment: I am getting CROS error in this

Comment: You're getting cors error. So why don't you allow cors on socket io? Is this really worth a bounty? c'mon man.

Comment: Cross is working fine all the other api which i have implemented

Comment: @TheFool i am unable to implemet socket in loopback 4

Comment: @AkashGupta regarding the CORS error, same thing happened to me when servers are running on `localhost`. But everything was fine on my server. Also, an addon on firefox may help you to bypass CORS. FYI

Answer (score 0):

What if you try this:

```
const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io").listen(server);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use request module. It ignores cors.

Or use raw sockets.

You could also use https://cors-anwhere.herokuapp.com/https://linkToYourWebHere you may have to add the header

```
Request-With: XmlHttpRequest
```